# How to display a widget side right on home page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please find the image, i am trying to add a widget in the place of red box:

[image: screenshot]

i used this code

```
<!-- RIGHT SIDEBAR -->
    <div id="side-right">
<!-- start feedwind code -->
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js">\x3C/script>');</script>
<script type="text/javascript">(function() {var params = {rssmikle_url: "http://classibook.com/feed",rssmikle_frame_width: "300",rssmikle_frame_height: "400",frame_height_by_article: "5",rssmikle_target: "_blank",rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",rssmikle_font_size: "15",rssmikle_border: "off",responsive: "on",rssmikle_css_url: "",text_align: "left",text_align2: "center",corner: "on",scrollbar: "off",autoscroll: "on",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "3",mcspeed: "30",sort: "Off",rssmikle_title: "on",rssmikle_title_sentence: "Free classifieds of india latest Listings",rssmikle_title_link: "",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",rssmikle_item_description: "on",item_link: "off",rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M %p",item_description_style: "text+tn",item_thumbnail: "full",item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",article_num: "15",rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();
</script>
<div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; ">
<a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a>
<!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.-->
</div>
<!-- end feedwind code -->
<!--  end  feedwind code -->
```

But i am not getting exactly side of latest listings on my home page http://classibook.com/ please check that, after placing that code on main.php it was displaying right below that latest listings on my site ...
please help me...

Comment: First of all a minified code does not help at all.

Now what I think you need is `float:left`. On both the latest listing container and the sidebar.

Comment: What's the PHP relation?

Comment: Sir i am not a developer, i dont have more knowledge about that, can u please help me more? and above code was rss feed widget .... <!-- RIGHT SIDEBAR -->
    <div id="side-right"> this is am adding... but it was displaying below the latest listings but not side of latest listings.... thank for u r reply

Comment: please don''t add Images Directly to your question Dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your main page, use `<div id="body">body content</div>` and for sidebar use `<div id="right-side">right side content</div>` and use the following css inside `<style></style>` in your page.

```
#body {
padding: 1em;
width:50%;
border: 8px solid darkred;
background:#3d594b;
}

#right-side {
padding: 1em;
width:30%;
border: 8px solid darkred;
background:#3d594b;
float: right;
}
```

I hope this will help.